# How to format neasted json array depends on conditions request json for api

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, angular4-forms

How to format neasted json array depends on conditions I have form request json for api

This is my front end json array
I created  this array using angular reactive forms

But Api need requires and not empty fields only

In above array is nested days->timings->breaks

conditions

1) if days not contain timings no need to sumbit(example: day-3 not contain timings so no need to submit)

2) if blocks, floors, room are empty no need to summit(example: day[1]-timing[1], timing[2], day[2]-timing[2])

3) if breaks are empty not need to submit the breaks array in days(example: day1[1]-> timings[3], day[2]->timings[2])

4

> ) in breks if mode is true (duration, quantity), if mode is true
>   (start time, end times are required

5) api no need nesting(just need  normal array)(example:[{}, {}, {}])

By floowing above conditions u can assume this array

I tried using for loops to solve it, but it's duplicate the things not well

Front end array

```
    {  
   "startDate":"10-05-2018",
   "endDate":"13-05-2018",
   "days":[  
      {  
         "dayId":1,
         "timings":[  
            {  
               "startTime":"10:00",
               "endTime":"12:00",
               "cycle":1,
               "blocks":1,
               "floors":2,
               "rooms":3,
               "breaks":[  
                  {  
                     "type":1,
                     "mode":false,
                     "startTime":"01:00",
                     "endTime":"02:00",
                     "duration":1,
                     "quantity":1
                  },
                  {  
                     "type":1,
                     "mode":true,
                     "startTime":"01:00",
                     "endTime":"02:00",
                     "duration":1,
                     "quantity":1
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "startTime":"10:00",
               "endTime":"12:00",
               "cycle":1,
               "blocks":"",
               "floors":"",
               "rooms":"",
               "breaks":[  
                  {  
                     "type":1,
                     "mode":false,
                     "startTime":"01:00",
                     "endTime":"02:00",
                     "duration":1,
                     "quantity":1
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "startTime":"10:00",
               "endTime":"12:00",
               "cycle":1,
               "blocks":"",
               "floors":"",
               "rooms":"",
               "breaks":[  

               ]
            },
            {  
               "startTime":"10:00",
               "endTime":"12:00",
               "cycle":1,
               "blocks":2,
               "floors":3,
               "rooms":3,
               "breaks":[  

               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "dayId":2,
         "timings":[  
            {  
               "startTime":"10:00",
               "endTime":"12:00",
               "cycle":1,
               "blocks":1,
               "floors":2,
               "rooms":3,
               "breaks":[  
                 {  
                     "type":1,
                     "mode":true,
                     "startTime":"01:00",
                     "endTime":"02:00",
                     "duration":1,
                     "quantity":1
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "startTime":"10:00",
               "endTime":"12:00",
               "cycle":1,
               "blocks":"",
               "floors":"",
               "rooms":"",
               "breaks":[  

               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "dayId":3,
         "timings":[  

         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**requested array**

```
    {  
   "start_date":"05-05-2018",
   "end_date":"31-07-2018",
   "branch_id":"2",
   "day":[  
      {  
         "id":"1",
         "start_time":"10:00",
         "end_time":"12:00",
         "breaks":[  
            {  
               "type":1,
               "mode":false,

               "duration":1,
               "quantity":1
            },
            {  
               "type":1,
               "mode":true,
               "startTime":"01:00",
               "endTime":"02:00",

            }
         ],
         "gen_repeat_cycle_id":"1",
         "room_id":"1",
         "floor_id":"2",
         "block_id":"3"
      },
      {  
         "id":"1",
         "start_time":"10:00",
         "end_time":"12:00",
         "breaks":[  
            {  
               "type":1,
               "mode":false,

               "duration":1,
               "quantity":1
            }
         ],
         "gen_repeat_cycle_id":"2"
      },
      {  
         "id":"1",
         "start_time":"10:00",
         "end_time":"12:00",
         "gen_repeat_cycle_id":"1"
      },
      {  
         "id":"1",
         "start_time":"10:00",
         "end_time":"12:00",
         "gen_repeat_cycle_id":"1",
         "room_id":"1",
         "floor_id":"2",
         "block_id":"3"
      },
      {  
         "id":"2",
         "start_time":"10:00",
         "end_time":"12:00",
         "breaks":[  
            {  
               "type":1,
               "mode":true,
               "startTime":"01:00",
               "endTime":"02:00",

            }
         ],
         "gen_repeat_cycle_id":"1",
         "room_id":"1",
         "floor_id":"2",
         "block_id":"3"
      },
      {  
         "id":"2",
         "start_time":"10:00",
         "end_time":"12:00",
         "gen_repeat_cycle_id":"1"
      }
   ]
}
```

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Updated)
This is the solution I came up with

```
  function processData(data) {
  var newData = {};
  newData.start_date = data.startDate;
  newData.end_date = data.endDate;
  newData.day = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < data.days.length; i++) {
    var currentDay = data.days[i];
    for(var j = 0; j < currentDay.timings.length; j++) {
        var currentTiming = currentDay.timings[j];
      var newTimingObject = {};
      newTimingObject.start_time = currentTiming.startTime;
      newTimingObject.end_time = currentTiming.endTime;
      newTimingObject.gen_repeat_cycle_id = currentTiming.cycle.toString();
      newTimingObject.id = currentDay.dayId.toString();

      if(currentTiming.breaks.length > 0) {
        var currentBreaks = [];
        for(var k = 0; k < currentTiming.breaks.length; k++) {
            var newBreakObject = {};
          newBreakObject.type = currentTiming.breaks[k].type;
          newBreakObject.mode = currentTiming.breaks[k].mode;
          if(currentTiming.breaks[k].mode === true) {
            newBreakObject.startTime = currentTiming.breaks[k].startTime;
            newBreakObject.endTime = currentTiming.breaks[k].endTime;
          } else {
            newBreakObject.duration = currentTiming.breaks[k].duration;
            newBreakObject.quantity = currentTiming.breaks[k].quantity;
          }
          currentBreaks.push(newBreakObject);
        }

        newTimingObject.breaks = currentBreaks;
      }

      if(currentTiming.blocks !== '') {
        newTimingObject.block_id = currentTiming.blocks.toString();
      }

      if(currentTiming.floors !== '') {
        newTimingObject.floor_id = currentTiming.floors.toString();
      }

      if(currentTiming.rooms !== '') {
        newTimingObject.room_id = currentTiming.rooms.toString();
      }

      newData.day.push(newTimingObject);
    }
  }

  return newData;
}
```

I have the solution in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dzeh5b9L/1/) check it out and I don't understand branch_id in the requested array.

Comment: You r solution is almost working , breaks array I can't add directly there is some conditions, can you please check the above edited question

Comment: Corrected the function to match your requested array.